# How do I win the KringleJammer mini-game?

Tags: achievements, atom-zombie-smasher

I'm trying to get the KringleJammer achievement for the upcoming Steam winter achievement hunt, but I can't seem to do it.

According to the achievement description, there are at least 7 waves, but I can't even get past wave 3. Sooner or later, a zombie reaches the civilians and sets off a massive chain reaction that I can't contain.

Are there any tips or strategies that might help?

Comment: This may be "cheating" and I don't know if it counts for the achievement, but have you tried loading a mod?  There are some that cause the game to only spawn a single slow moving zombie per round.    That's an extreme case, but you can scale the difficulty if you're just playing it casually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a few tips [here](http://neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?p=33550670):

> A good tip was to not do too well on the early waves, because every
>   civilian left alive is another zombie you'll have to kill later when
>   you will already have too many zombies to kill. Let most of the people
>   die early; as long as a single one is left alive, you don't lose. An
>   even better tip was that the game speed modifiers from the main game
>   work in this mode. Use the space bar or plus and minus to reduce the
>   speed as low as ten percent and it becomes a cakewalk. And if the
>   achievement doesn't pop up, start a new campaign, go into the first
>   area, and concede.

And a few more [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=27030108):

> Some tips on how to beat the waves: you have 40-50 seconds per wave
>   and the only way to lose a wave is to let the time expire or lose all
>   of your humans. A major outbreak could end it for you in the later
>   stages if the zombies infect a giant pack of humans (which they almost
>   certainly will).
>
> The best way I've found to deal with an outbreaks is, in the earlier
>   stages when you have plenty of time to spare, just let the zombies
>   infect a manageable amount of humans; so you'll have less of them to
>   worry about latter on. If you do this you shouldn't have much of a
>   need for bombs and can neglect picking them up if there's something
>   else you need to focus on.

Comment: Got the achievement, thank you. For some reason I was all like "PROTECT EVERYTHING", when really I should have been maximizing the civilian casualties. Counter-intuitive, given the theme of the game, but whatever.

Comment: +1 I did this at 100% on my first try.  I think letting a good portion of them die early on is the key.